# No Error in Facebook script but still not showing result

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, fbjs

I am very new to FaceBook Javascript API. I need help to get the fiends list according to the Friend List i have created. Like 'Grads, School, Friends, Worked with' (All of these are self created).

This is so far I have done right now. I am successfully logged in and have proper access_token allocated to this session. After that I run this.

```
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if( response.session ){
            *FB.api('friendlist', '/me/friendlists', function(){
                **alert('got the friendlist');
            });
        }else{
            alert('User not logged in.');
        }
    },{scope: 'email,read_friendlists'});
```

On this code

`* this runs OK without any exceptions?`

`** this alert never invokes?`

Just want to ask few things.

Is there a proper way to see the exception. If we have a callback for exception as well?

and How to get the List of FriendList from FB using JS API.

Thanks,

Talha Ahmed khan

Comment: Facebook Returns and Object which you can't alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this and it seems to work

```
 <div id="listsDiv"></div>

 <script>
 var listsDiv = document.getElementById('listsDiv');
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
 if (response.status != 'connected') {
 listsDiv.innerHTML = '<em>You are not connected</em>';
 return;
 }


 });

 var perms = function(){
 FB.api('/me/friendlists', function(result) {

 var markup = '';
 var lists = result.data;
 for(var i in lists){
   markup += lists[i].name +'<br />';
 }
 listsDiv .innerHTML = markup;
 });
 }
 FB.login(perms, { scope: 'read_friendlists' });
 </script>
```

You can test a lot of this stuff out at

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, FB.api returns a response object which you can use to debug the error.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

revised code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
        if( response.session ){
            FB.api('friendlist', '/me/friendlists', function(response){
                alert(response.error);
            });
        }else{
            alert('User not logged in.');
        }
    },{scope: 'email,read_friendlists'});
```

if you want to see what properties are on 'response', you could use something like firebug or chrome's debug console and instead of:

```
alert(reponse.error);
```

you could use

```
console.log(response);
```